# How to select a day in a calendar using Selenium on Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, datepicker, calendar

Going to https://lonnie-poole-package-plan-v2.book.teeitup.com/ and clicking on the Date brings me to a calendar. I am able to get all the way to select the month and year, but I have no idea on how to select the day I want. I know I am supposed to find the general xpath template that each day follows but I have no idea how to find it. Any help would be appreciated. Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from config import keys
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

def order(k):
    chr_options = Options()
    chr_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver', options=chr_options)
    driver.get(k['website_url'])

    time.sleep(1)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*.[@id="app"]/div/section/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/button').click()
    while True:
        text = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app-body"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/p').get_attribute('innerText')
        if text == k["month_year"]:
            break
        else:
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app-body"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/button[2]/span[1]/span').click()

    #issue begins here: this is where I am trying to select a day
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app-body"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[5]/button/span[1][contains(text(),"20")]')
if __name__ == '__main__':
order(keys)
```

Comment: Why not just go to the date directly? I clicked on a day then checked the URL and saw `https://lonnie-poole-package-plan-v2.book.teeitup.com/?date=2020-12-31`

Comment: You want to be clicking the button and not the span. You can use /parent::button after you find the span you want.

Answer (score 0):

This works for finding the date buttons.

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//button[@class="jss530 jss556 jss772"]')
```

Comment: thanks but how do I use this to get the day I want?

Answer (score 0):

Just get the button parent to the span with day text in the div with role document.

```
driver.get('https://lonnie-poole-package-plan-v2.book.teeitup.com/')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
#issue begins here: this is where I am trying to select a day

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div/div/div/section/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/button"))).click()
day = 31
try:
   wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@role='document']//span[text()='{}']/parent::button[@tabindex='0']".format(str(day))))).click()
except:
   print('Not valid date')
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

[image]

Comment: When I run this code it prints out 'Not valid date'. Is the xpath wrong?